# Change spring jpa existing table column type

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using spring boot and jpa and I have an existing table with attribute as VARCHAR 255:

```
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
```

I tried to change it to longtext with no success:

```
@Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "longtext")
private String description;
```

My configuration in the application.properties file regarding Hibernate ddl is set to update:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Is it possible to change VARCAR 255 to longtext? if it does, How do I do it?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: As far I know you have to do it manually by mySQL workbench or something else. Property type are not changed if it is defined once. So do it manually!

Answer (score 4):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

will not do following changes

- Delete a column which is no longer in entity
- Modify existing column.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha?lq=1) for more details

Comment: this doesn't answer the question "how to update field type?". This could have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

spring-data-jpa ddl ‘update’ will not change exist colums，neither update nor delete.

Comment: then what will?

Comment: I mean how do we update the tables for existing entities for example if we delete a field from a JPA Entity or change the type of it it won't be represented in the database

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue
Your current configuration won't update

The best way to do this is through migrations using flyway
Documentation : https://flywaydb.org/documentation/

you can write sql queries in your project and alter the same column in your entity.